# Uniquely identifying (Android) user

Tags: android, security

I will start by providing some context and requirements, so please bear with me.

I am developing an app that will allow users to exchange some information - let's assume a 20-character string for simplicity. The information should only be exchanged when users are physically close to each other (via NFC, Bluetooth or WiFi).

What I want to do is whenever John Smith sends me said string, I want my app to recognize that it is indeed John Smith (i.e. his account). John Smith may use this account on different devices, so I am not interested in the device id.

But here's the catch: I may have never, ever met John Smith before, but my app still needs to recognize him. And this is where I'm stuck. What could John Smith's app possible send me to uniquely identify him (and prevent me from impersonating him*)?

**Question:** How can I uniquely identify this (Android) user (without being able to impersonate him)?

*This is important. If John Smith was sending his private identifier, then I could create a malicious app that waits for that ID. I want to prevent that as much as possible. John Smith should be able to send that 20-character string to complete strangers. It's fine if they know the string came from John Smith, as long as they won't be able to impersonate him.

LE: I am open to all kinds of suggestions. My main desire is to keep the process straightforward, fast and easy for the users. Please feel free to suggest your ideas.

Comment: Can all of John Smith's devices access some secure file storage that is attached to his account? E.g. to store a key?

Comment: @Perseids I am open to all kinds of suggestions, as long as they don't make the whole process slow or require to user to go through complicated set ups etc.

Comment: Okay, assuming you have a central server that is completely trustworthy I would suggest that for each user you create an asymmetric signature key. You can sign that signature key with your own service key to bind the end user key to his id, let's call the result a certificate. When John Smith logs in to your service from a new device you sent him (i.e. his app) his private signature key and the corresponding certificate.

Comment: When Alice's app want's to authenticate John's device it sends it a 128 bit random number as a challenge. John's app answers with a signature on the 128 bit random number as well as with the certificate. Alice's app checks the signature on the certificate and on the random number (using the public key contained in the certificate) and can then be sure with whom Alice is talking.

Comment: To my mind comes: user creates an account with his data (name, email, whatever). A GUID is generated and assigned to the user. It's stored in some database on a server.  Now application can verify GUID by requesting data from the server

Answer (score 0):

This could be an application for asymmetric cryptography.  John Smith could create a public/private key pair and sign all his communications using the private key.  Note that this approach still has a few weaknesses.  First, it does not exactly prove that the sender of the message is John Smith; it proves that the sender of the message has access to John Smith's private key.  So it depends on the security of the key.  Second, depending on your application, it may be necessary to validate that the first person who publishes their public key and says "I'm John Smith" is really John Smith.  You would normally do this via face-to-face contact or some other relatively trusted side channel such as a phone call.  Third, the receiver of the message needs a way to verify that you have certified John Smith's identity, so you need to sign John Smith's public key with your own private key, and embed your public key in the app.